# What is the Purpose of Import Modules Without Export or Consumption within File

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, export

I have seen this following pattern within index.js file and I am left scratching my head. What would be the purpose of the following code below, considering:

- The imported module is not being consumed within this module/file
- There is no export of the imported module

The following code is all there is within the index.js file (yes, just one line):

```
import '../modules/index.js';
```

To elaborate, the index.js file is importing from '../modules/index.js'. That is it, there is no other code within the file whatsoever.

Comment: "The imported module is not being consumed within this module/file"... care to elaborate how you have verified this?

Comment: @Pineda updated the question.

Comment: The update doesn't help. What other code is set up in the project? What are the contents of '../modules/index.js'.

Comment: If that import statement is all there is in that file, then it's just making the code from the import location available for the file to use...

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I'm aware of where one might want to do an import without utilizing anything imported is when the imported file has some form of side effect that happens simply by evaluating the code, such as defining a global variable. In this case, simply importing the code will cause that code to be run. If you can indicate more about the contents of `modules/index.js` we might be able to get to a more defined answer of what's happening in this case.